# crop an image multipile times using drawImage() canvas?

Tags: html5-canvas, drawimage

I have this code and successfully croped the left corner , but I need to crop all 4 corners of this image ,can it be done with the same object?

I have this code and successfully croped the left corner , but I need to crop all 4 corners of this image ,can it be done with the same object?

[the croped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5391.png)

```
//Global variables
  var myImage = new Image(); // Create a new blank image.

  // Load the image and display it.
  function displayImage() {

    // Get the canvas element.
    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

    // Make sure you got it.
    if (canvas.getContext) {

      // Specify 2d canvas type.
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      // When the image is loaded, draw it.
      myImage.onload = function() {

        // Load the image into the context.
        ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0);

        // Get and modify the image data.
        changeImage();
      }

      // Define the source of the image.
      myImage.src = "ice.jpg";
    }
  }

  function changeImage() {

    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.lineWidth = "70";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0,0,10,0*Math.PI,0.5*Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
  }
   </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="displayImage()">

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200">
    </canvas>

    </body>

   </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually draw the four quarter circle:

```js
//Global variables
  var myImage = new Image(); // Create a new blank image.
 
  // Load the image and display it.
  function displayImage() {

    // Get the canvas element.
    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

    // Make sure you got it.
    if (canvas.getContext) {

      // Specify 2d canvas type.
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      // When the image is loaded, draw it.
      myImage.onload = function() {
        canvas.width = myImage.width;
        canvas.height = myImage.height;
        // Load the image into the context.
        ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0);

        // Get and modify the image data.
        changeImage(myImage.width, myImage.height);
      }

      // Define the source of the image.
      myImage.src = "http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg";
    }
  }

  function changeImage(w,h) {
    var r = 70;
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.arc(0,0,r,0*Math.PI,0.5*Math.PI);
    ctx.moveTo(0,r);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(w,0,r, -0.5*Math.PI,-1*Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,h);
    ctx.arc(0,h,r, -0.5*Math.PI,0*Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(w,h);
    ctx.arc(w,h,r, -1*Math.PI,-0.5*Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }

displayImage();
```

```html
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200">
    </canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Kind of what @AndreaBogazzi says, but kind of not...

Yes, you **can** draw all 4 of the corner cutouts using a single path.

This is done by drawing a cutout circle and then picking up the "brush" and moving it to the center of the next cutout.

You must pick up the brush or otherwise you will get a line drawn that connects the centerpoints of each cutout circle.

1. Begin a single path: `ctx.beginPath()`
2. Draw an arc: `ctx.arc(0,0,cutRadius,0,Math.PI*2)`
3. Pick up the "brush" and move it to the center of the next arc: `ctx.moveTo(w,0)`
4. Draw an arc: `ctx.arc(w,0,cutRadius,0,Math.PI*2)`
5. Pick up the "brush" and move it to the center of the next arc: `ctx.moveTo(w,h)`
6. Draw an arc: `ctx.arc(w,h,cutRadius,0,Math.PI*2)`
7. Pick up the "brush" and move it to the center of the next arc: `ctx.moveTo(0,h)`
8. Draw an arc: `ctx.arc(0,h,cutRadius,0,Math.PI*2)`
9. Fill all 4 cutout circles: `ctx.fill()`

Note: since the "brush" begins at [0,0] you don't have to `moveTo(0,0)` after step#1.

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var cutRadius=10;
var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/reef.jpg";
function start(){
  cw=canvas.width=img.width;
  ch=canvas.height=img.height
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  changeImage();
}

function changeImage() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0,0,cutRadius,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.moveTo(cw,0);
  ctx.arc(cw,0,cutRadius,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.moveTo(cw,ch);
  ctx.arc(cw,ch,cutRadius,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.moveTo(0,ch);
  ctx.arc(0,ch,cutRadius,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```